# column update without using trigger

Tags: sql-server, plsql, triggers, procedures

SCENARIO:

I have two tables, table1(col1 date) and table2(col2 varchar(20)).

REQUIREMENT:

Whenever anyone updated the value in col2, todays date should be inserted/updated in col1.
It should be done without using triggers.

Now, I cannot think of anything possible to do it. So, I need your help; PLEASE.

Thank you.

Comment: Why must it be done without triggers?

Comment: Why do you have PL/SQL and trigger tags if triggers aren't allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done automatically without using triggers.
You need to manually run a statement for updating table1. Running both update table2 and update table1 statements inside a transaction you can ensure the integrity of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Call a stored procedure to save the data, and it can update the date.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind a delay, you could schedule a regular job to poll table2 for changes and update table1. There are performance considerations, but just sayin' - it's *possible* to do it without triggers; you have to just worry about inconsistent data (a problem which can be mitigated).